# Trigger evaluate which rows of the deleted ones do not exist in the new data and insert them into the new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table where rows are deleted every 15 minutes and then new rows are inserted. I need a trigger to evaluate which rows of the deleted ones do not exist in the new data and insert them into the new table..

```
CREATE TRIGGER newTrigger ON SomeTable
AFTER  DELETE, INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;      
    INSERT INTO SAP_ZINDICADORES_CDU_HIS_D
    SELECT NumeroPedido
          ,Material
          ,Paquete
          ,GETDATE()
    FROM deleted old
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM inserted new 
                      WHERE
                      new.IdRow = old.IdRow
```

My previous code insert all the deleted rows

Thanks in advance

Comment: The table is deleted? Or the rows are deleted? What does/doesn't work about your existing code?

Comment: The rows are deleted. My trigger insert all deleted rows into the new table.

Comment: Well you can't delete them, then check which ones are missing? You need to build some sort of merge statement, probably long before the update hits a trigger. You really need to clarify your question with a [mre].

Comment: The inserted and delated pseudo-tables are only populated based on the single statement involved. you **only** get records in both inserted and delated for an 'update' statement, where you get the before and after values. For a delete statement you only get records in deleted, and for an insert on records in inserted.

Comment: You're going to have to rethink your logic.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot @DaleK